# How can i run the add migration command

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I installed the following packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design(7.0.2)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite(7.0.2)
```

I already installed Entity Framework Core.

When I tried to run this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration
```

I get this error:

> No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.

I already tried go to the project folder using cd "C:..." it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using the `--project` flag? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet Is there any more to the error message? What happens if you add the `-v` flag?

Comment: I already tried that command:
"dotnet --project mypath ef migrations add InitialMigration".
I'm sorry but can you be more specific about the -v flag? My terminal skills are kinda bad.

Comment: The `-v` flag is "verbose", as seen in this table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options. I recommend you read the whole page.

Comment: I did that and thanks for advice! But I can't copy all the terminal outputs here I don't know how to show you those. Can you give an advice about it. Thanks for your time it looks like too hard to help who don't know how to use stack overflow. So thank you about that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several projects in one solution or if you have deleted and created a project several times, you may encounter this error (of course, there are other reasons).

This error occurred because Migration could not automatically determine which project to select.

You can solve this problem by adding your project name

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --project TestAPI
```

[image]

Comment: It solved with this comment, thank you all.